# Freertos + STM32 - thread memory overflow with malloc

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded, stm32, freertos

I'm working with stm32+rtos to implement a file system based on spi flash. For freertos, I adopted heap_1 implementation. This is how i create my task.

```
osThreadDef(Task_Embedded, Task_VATEmbedded, osPriorityNormal, 0, 2500);
  VATEmbeddedTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(Task_Embedded), NULL);
```

I allocated 10000 bytes of memory to this thread.

and in this thread. I tried to write data into flash. In the first few called it worked successfully. but somehow it crash when i tried more time of write.

```
VATAPI_RESULT STM32SPIWriteSector(void *writebuf, uint8_t* SectorAddr, uint32_t buff_size){



    if(STM32SPIEraseSector(SectorAddr) == VAT_SUCCESS){
        DBGSTR("ERASE SECTOR - 0x%2x %2x %2x", SectorAddr[0], SectorAddr[1], SectorAddr[2]);
    }else return VAT_UNKNOWN;
    if(STM32SPIProgram_multiPage(writebuf, SectorAddr, buff_size) == VAT_SUCCESS){
        DBGSTR("WRTIE SECTOR SUCCESSFUL");
        return VAT_SUCCESS;
    }else return VAT_UNKNOWN;

    return VAT_UNKNOWN;

}
```

.

```
VATAPI_RESULT STM32SPIProgram_multiPage(uint8_t *writebuf, uint8_t *writeAddr, uint32_t buff_size){
    VATAPI_RESULT nres;
    uint8_t tmpaddr[3] = {writeAddr[0], writeAddr[1], writeAddr[2]};
    uint8_t* sectorBuf = malloc(4096 * sizeof(uint8_t));
    uint8_t* pagebuf = malloc(255* sizeof(uint8_t));
    memset(&sectorBuf[0],0,4096);
    memset(&pagebuf[0],0,255);
    uint32_t i = 0, tmp_convert1, times = 0;


    if(buff_size < Page_bufferSize)
        times = 1;
    else{
        times = buff_size / (Page_bufferSize-1);
        if((times%(Page_bufferSize-1))!=0)
            times++;
    }

    /* Note : According to winbond flash feature, the last bytes of every 256 bytes should be 0, so we need to plus one byte on every 256 bytes*/
    i = 0;
    while(i < times){
        memset(&pagebuf[0], 0, Page_bufferSize - 1);
        memcpy(&pagebuf[0], &writebuf[i*255], Page_bufferSize - 1);
        memcpy(&sectorBuf[i*Page_bufferSize], &pagebuf[0], Page_bufferSize - 1);
        sectorBuf[((i+1)*Page_bufferSize)-1] = 0;
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while(i < times){
        if((nres=STM32SPIPageProgram(&sectorBuf[Page_bufferSize*i], &tmpaddr[0], Page_bufferSize)) != VAT_SUCCESS){
            DBGSTR("STM32SPIProgram_allData write data fail on %d times!",i);
            free(sectorBuf);
            free(pagebuf);
            return nres;
        }
        tmp_convert1 = (tmpaddr[0]<<16 | tmpaddr[1]<<8 | tmpaddr[2]) + Page_bufferSize;
        tmpaddr[0] = (tmp_convert1&0xFF0000) >> 16;
        tmpaddr[1] = (tmp_convert1&0xFF00) >>8;
        tmpaddr[2] = 0x00;
        i++;
    }
    free(sectorBuf);
    free(pagebuf);
    return nres;
}
```

I open the debugger and it seems like it crash when i malloced "sectorbuf" in function "STM32SPIProgram_multiPage", what Im confused is that i did free the memory after "malloc". anyone has idea about it?

> arm-none-eabi-size "RTOS.elf"
>    text        data         bss       dec    hex  filename
>   77564       988  100756  179308   2bc6c RTOS.elf

Comment: oh. Before, I put "sectorBuf" and "pagebuf" as global variables, then all the function work well. but it consume too much RAM if i do so. that why now i used dynamic memory instead.

Comment: so i think the problem is caused by using dynamic memory.

Comment: Have you allocate memory for heap manage by malloc (heap_1.c and its associated heap size is totally independent of malloc)

Comment: I'm just wondering with the heap_.c, where "sectorbuf" is storing. i read the document. it says it is storing in the heap of platform.

Comment: hum... I think you mix up with heap_3.c

Comment: you mean in my case. i should adopted heap_3.c?

Comment: if you choose heap_3, you have to configure your system heap management, which can be difficult on embedded system, specially if your a beginner. prefer maybe heap_4 or heap_5 and using pvPortMalloc/pvPortFree. Read about each of their capability and choose according what you want to do

Comment: Dynamic merory does not necessarily use less RAM.

Comment: the elf says that bss is about 100k. my platform has  128k ram. when i compile my project. if bss is more than 128k it said ram overflow. but if i use  dynamic memory instead of global the bss decrease so i can allocate more stack size to threads. do i make it wrong? confused.. what that bss really stand for?

Comment: Not even checking for errors, e.g. `malloc` - potential UB, case closed!

Comment: @Pawan: "Block Storage Segment". But if you already have a >128KiB BSS, there is definitively something wrong in your project. Either the code or the linker configuration file. That can be quite a difficult task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [the man](http://www.freertos.org/a00111.html#heap_1)

> **Memory Management**
>
> [...]
>
> If RTOS objects are created dynamically then the standard C library malloc() and free() functions can sometimes be used for the purpose, but ...
>
> they are not always available on embedded systems,
>   they take up valuable code space,
>   they are not thread safe, and
>   they are not deterministic (the amount of time taken to execute the function will differ from call to call)
>   ... so more often than not an alternative memory allocation implementation is required.
>   One embedded / real time system can have very different RAM and timing requirements to another - so a single RAM allocation algorithm will only ever be appropriate for a subset of applications.
>
> **To get around this problem, FreeRTOS keeps the memory allocation API in its portable layer. The portable layer is outside of the source files that implement the core RTOS functionality, allowing an application specific implementation appropriate for the real time system being developed to be provided. When the RTOS kernel requires RAM, instead of calling malloc(), it instead calls pvPortMalloc(). When RAM is being freed, instead of calling free(), the RTOS kernel calls vPortFree().**
>
> [...]

<sup>(Emphasis mine.)</sup>

So the meaning is that if you use directly `malloc`, `FreeRTOS` is not able to handle the heap consumed by the system function. Same if you choose `heap_3` management that is a simple `malloc` wrapper.

Take also note that the memory management you choose has no free capability.

> **heap_1.c**
>
> This is the simplest implementation of all. **It does not permit memory to be freed** once it has been allocated. Despite this, heap_1.c is appropriate for a large number of embedded applications. This is because many small and deeply embedded applications create all the tasks, queues, semaphores, etc. required when the system boots, and then use all of these objects for the lifetime of program (until the application is switched off again, or is rebooted). Nothing ever gets deleted.
>   The implementation simply subdivides a single array into smaller blocks as RAM is requested. The total size of the array (the total size of the heap) is set by configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE - which is defined in FreeRTOSConfig.h. The configAPPLICATION_ALLOCATED_HEAP FreeRTOSConfig.h configuration constant is provided to allow the heap to be placed at a specific address in memory.
>
> The xPortGetFreeHeapSize() API function returns the total amount of heap space that remains unallocated, allowing the configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE setting to be optimised.
>
> **The heap_1 implementation:**
>
> Can be used if your application never deletes a task, queue, semaphore, mutex, etc. (which actually covers the majority of applications in which FreeRTOS gets used).
>   Is always deterministic (always takes the same amount of time to execute) and cannot result in memory fragmentation.
>   Is very simple and allocated memory from a statically allocated array, meaning it is often suitable for use in applications that do not permit true dynamic memory allocation.

<sup>(Emphasis mine.)</sup>

Side note: You **have always to**  check `malloc` return value `!= NULL`.

Comment: what does that mean that memory management i choose( heap_1.c) has no free capacity? does that mean if i call malloc. i cant free that memory section?

Comment: No. Cose of to use `heap_1` memory management you have to use `pvPortMalloc()`, not `malloc` directly. In case you use correctly `heap_1` function you'll not be able to free heap allocated memory.

Comment: In FreeRTOS you have an abstraction of dynamic allocated memory and it provides you 5 different implementations. first one (heap_1) only authorize malloc but when you call free it does nothing (useful in many embedded project which only allocate one time memory for tasks and never free it). heap_2 is a little more complex and does free memory but have a poor memory management. heap_3 is only a wrapper to malloc and free. heap_4 and heap_5 have a more complex memory management, specially for free memory. In your case you have to choose one of 2 last and use `pvPortMalloc` and `pvPortFree`

Comment: i still dont get what that mean "you'll not be able to free heap allocated memory."

Comment: It is simply not implemented. Look at the source file.

Comment: @Pawan it's means pvPortFree does nothing. Remember that heap_X from FreeRTOS which provide `pvPortMalloc` and `pvPortFree` _are totally independent_ of malloc and free system function

Comment: If you want to use malloc and free you have to configure your project to have, near FreeRTOS heap management, a system heap management. Or use one of heap_X of FreeRTOS with pvPortMalloc and pvPortFree in replacement of malloc/free

Comment: i guess i should just config my project with heap_4, and use pvPortMalloc and pvPortFree instead of malloc and free?

Comment: @Pawan probably yes but I don't know about all of your requirements

Comment: It Seems ok to me, based on the partial view of your application.

Comment: i just removed my bug. it works fine now. you guys are legit.